# How to add LUIS Key and App Id in Custom Skill Template?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a new C# project using virtual assistant skill template. Where should I add the LUIS API Key and App Id ? When I run the project I'm getting this error.

[image]

I have already added LUIS key and app id in my appsettings.json fie.

[image]

Comment: Have you set up the LUIS application?

Comment: You do not have to add the LuisAppId, LuisAPIHostName, LuisAPIKey in the appsettings.json. You might have to double check if your LUIS app is set up correctly. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/skills/src/csharp/todoskill/todoskill) is the link to the todoskill sample. You can compare your project files with that of the todoskills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add Luis AppId,subscription key etc. in cognitivemodels.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the wrong value for LuisAPIHostName, in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) it shows that it should be in the form `<your region>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`